# Generate inputStream from Itext pdf source

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to generate an inputStream Object from a file generated by iText library. These are the first bytes in the file:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
2 0 obj
<</Length 1571/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
)©toÿqûºÒç¹Ð4)ÖÞ{Ñ$,·7?ÂDCþDÆü½
```

Comment: Your question was wrong. I corrected it. You aren't creating "text"; you are creating a PDF file (or document). You want the bytes of that file to be available as an `InputStream`, but you aren't telling us if you created the file on disk (in which case you can simple create a `FileInputStream`) or if you created the file in memory (in which case you have a `ByteArrayOutputStream` that you can easily convert to a `ByteArrayInputStream`).

Answer (score 9):

Suppose that you created your PDF like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
document.close();
```

In that case you can convert the `OutputStream` to an `InputStream` like this:

```
InputStream in = ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

Suppose that you created the PDF like this:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("my.pdf");
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
document.close();
```

Then you can create an `InputStream` like this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("my.pdf");
```

Comment: Should that be InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());